# .slideDown() .slideUp() no funciona jquery

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
 $("#accion_stock_remove").click(function(){
        if($("#accion_stock_remove").is(':checked')){
            $("#stock_roto_yes").removeClass("hidden");
            $("#stock_roto").slideDown("slow");
            $("#stock_roto").attr("disabled",false);
            $("#stock_noroto").attr("disabled",false);

        }
    });
$("#accion_stock_add").click(function(){
        if($("#accion_stock_add").is(':checked')){
            $("#stock_roto_yes").addClass("hidden");
            $("#stock_roto").attr("disabled",true);
            $("#stock_noroto").attr("disabled",true);

        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="radio" class="hidden checkBox" name="accion_stock" id="accion_stock_add"/>
                    <label for="accion_stock_add" class="checkBoxLabel" style="width: 100% !important">Añadir</label>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="radio" class="hidden checkBox" name="accion_stock" id="accion_stock_remove"/>
                    <label for="accion_stock_remove" class="checkBoxLabel" style="width: 100% !important">Quitar</label>
                </div>

                <div class="row hidden" id="stock_roto_yes">
                    <div class="col-md-12"><center>ES STOCK ROTO?</center></div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="radio" class="hidden checkBox" name="stock_roto" id="stock_roto" value="roto" disabled/>
                        <label for="stock_roto" class="checkBoxLabel" style="width: 100% !important">SÍ</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="radio" class="hidden checkBox" name="stock_roto" id="stock_noroto" value="noroto" disabled/>
                        <label for="stock_noroto" class="checkBoxLabel" style="width: 100% !important">NO</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Lo que necesito es que al hacer click en el boton `Quitar` se despliegue con una animación `slideDown()` el div `stock_roto_yes` y al hacer click en `Añadir` que se cierre con una animación `slideUp()` pero no me funciona, y la consola del inspector tampoco me dice que haya error.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta añadir tu código cuando el documento esté cargado y listo:

```
$(function() {
     $("#accion_stock_remove").click(function(){
        if($("#accion_stock_remove").is(':checked')){
            $("#stock_roto_yes").removeClass("hidden");
            $("#stock_roto").slideDown("slow");
            $("#stock_roto").attr("disabled",false);
            $("#stock_noroto").attr("disabled",false);

        }
    });
$("#accion_stock_add").click(function(){
        if($("#accion_stock_add").is(':checked')){
            $("#stock_roto_yes").addClass("hidden");
            $("#stock_roto").attr("disabled",true);
            $("#stock_noroto").attr("disabled",true);

        }
    });
});
```

Lo mas probable es que se ejecute antes el `jQuery` que la creación de los elementos a los que haces referencia.

Answer (score 0):

Exacto, intenta meterlo dentro de

```html
jQuery(document).ready(         
          function(){
$("#accion_stock_remove").click(function(){
        if($("#accion_stock_remove").is(':checked')){
            $("#stock_roto_yes").removeClass("hidden");
            $("#stock_roto").slideDown("slow");
            $("#stock_roto").attr("disabled",false);
            $("#stock_noroto").attr("disabled",false);

        }
    });
$("#accion_stock_add").click(function(){
        if($("#accion_stock_add").is(':checked')){
            $("#stock_roto_yes").addClass("hidden");
            $("#stock_roto").attr("disabled",true);
            $("#stock_noroto").attr("disabled",true);

        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es la clase `hidden` cual tiene la propiedad: `display: none!important;`

Solución: He eliminado la clase `hidden` y he añadido medio `CSS` al elemento `stock_roto_yes` la propiedad `display: none;` (sin !important)

```js
$("#accion_stock_remove").click(function(){
  
  if($("#accion_stock_remove").is(':checked')){

    // Eliminado
    //$("#stock_roto_yes").removeClass("hidden");
    
    $("#stock_roto_yes").slideDown("slow");
    $("#stock_roto").attr("disabled",false);
    $("#stock_noroto").attr("disabled",false);
  }
});

$("#accion_stock_add").click(function(){
  
  if($("#accion_stock_add").is(':checked')){
    
    // Eliminado
    //$("#stock_roto_yes").addClass("hidden");
    
    $("#stock_roto_yes").slideUp("slow");
    $("#stock_roto").attr("disabled",true);
    $("#stock_noroto").attr("disabled",true);
  }
});
```

```css
#stock_roto_yes {
  
  display: none; /* sin !important */
  
  background-color: red; /* solo para demostración */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <input type="radio" class="hidden checkBox" name="accion_stock" id="accion_stock_add"/>
  <label for="accion_stock_add" class="checkBoxLabel" style="width: 100% !important">Añadir</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <input type="radio" class="hidden checkBox" name="accion_stock" id="accion_stock_remove"/>
  <label for="accion_stock_remove" class="checkBoxLabel" style="width: 100% !important">Quitar</label>
</div>
<div class="row" id="stock_roto_yes">
  <div class="col-md-12"><center>ES STOCK ROTO?</center></div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="radio" class="hidden checkBox" name="stock_roto" id="stock_roto" value="roto" disabled/>
    <label for="stock_roto" class="checkBoxLabel" style="width: 100% !important">SÍ</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="radio" class="hidden checkBox" name="stock_roto" id="stock_noroto" value="noroto" disabled/>
    <label for="stock_noroto" class="checkBoxLabel" style="width: 100% !important">NO</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

En `jQuery` cuando usamos por ejemplo `fadeIn(), slideUp(), show()... etc` necesitan la propiedad `display: none;` o `$(elemento).hide();` el cual es equivalente.

> Cuando se emplea `important` en una declaración de estilo, esta
>   declaración sobreescribe a cualquier otra. Aunque técnicamente
>   `!important`  no tiene nada que ver con especificidad, interactúa
>   directamente con esta. Sin embargo, el uso de !important, es una mala
>   práctica y debería evitarse porque hace que el código sea más difícil
>   de depurar porque rompre la cascada [(artículo en ingles)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade) natural de
>   las hojas de estilo. Cuando dos declaraciones en conflicto con el
>   `!important` son aplicadas al mismo elemento, se aplicará la declaración
>   con mayor especificidad.

Fuente Mozilla: [La excepción !important](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad#La_excepci%C3%B3n_!important)